# groovy wrap return of function in parens?

Tags: groovy

I have a method which I'm calling like this:

```
def var = powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
        get-blah -argb sdf -argc ssss`
        -argd wwwww -arge iiiiii
        """
var = var.trim()
```

I'm doing that because this doesn't work:

```
def var = powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
        get-blah -argb sdf -argc ssss`
        -argd wwwww -arge iiiiii
        """.trim()
```

nor does this seem to work:

```
def var = (powershell returnStdout: true, script: """
        get-blah -argb sdf -argc ssss`
        -argd wwwww -arge iiiiii
        """).trim()
```

Is there a way I can trim the return value with reassigning the var? This question isn't about this specific method/function I'm calling, just a general question about how to do this with groovy or if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
def var = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: """
        get-blah -argb sdf -argc ssss`
        -argd wwwww -arge iiiiii
        """).trim()
```

?

Comment: yes that works. Could you explain that? Why didn't `(powershell returnStdout:..` work? Sorry, Im still trying to wrap my head around groovy structures.

Comment: @red888 I think it should work as well since you call trim() on the whole wrapped with parenthesis function result. What I can tell you is just you need a bit more experience to know when and when not use it. You can file a bug and get the details.

Comment: Second example is likely trimming the script, and not the output.   I would expect the third to work.